# How can I extract the estimated home value from Zillow for all homes

Tags: python, web-scraping, zillow

Edit: I am most comfortable with python, but can also use R... even if I can't do a thousand homes at a time. Something that can automate the process and let me do a few hundred or even a couple dozen would be great

Is there a straight forward way to extract the address and current month as well as last months Zestimate history prices from Table view for all houses within a search area

For example lets say I wanted to grab data from a map like this with 1,773 homes:

https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/?searchQueryState=%7B%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22north%22%3A41.92858933965862%2C%22south%22%3A41.60594278944949%2C%22east%22%3A-87.79580003222657%2C%22west%22%3A-88.26958543261719%7D%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isEntirePlaceForRent%22%3Atrue%2C%22isRoomForRent%22%3Afalse%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22%22%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%7D

I then wanted to grab the address as well as Zestimate for Feb 2024 and Jan 2024 for all 1,773 homes

[Example table for one home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JP9K.png)

I've attempted to scrap data for a single home and was vaguely successful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.